# PubSub does not work in Client page but works in Graphql playground - TypeError: data.getPosts is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, graphql, publish-subscribe, react-apollo, apollo-server

I am trying to make a Social app using **MongoDB, Express, React, Node, Graphql with Apollo** , I am following a video from freecodecamp : [Link to the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1mdAPFq2Os)

I am using **`pubsub` to achieve a realtime functionality**, like when ever a new post has been added it should show up in the home page.

I might have missed the code of some file that's why
I am dropping a **link to my github repo containing the whole project** : [Link to the github repo](https://github.com/lorstenoplo/merng-app)

**Home.js**:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { Grid, Transition } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import { AuthContext } from '../context/auth';
import PostCard from '../components/PostCard';
import PostForm from '../components/PostForm';
import { FETCH_POSTS_QUERY } from '../util/graphql';

function Home() {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);
  if(data) {
    const { posts } = data || [];
    return (
      <Grid columns={3}>
        <Grid.Row className="page-title">
          <h1>Recent Posts</h1>
        </Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Row>
          {user && (
            <Grid.Column>
              <PostForm />
            </Grid.Column>
          )}
          {loading && <h1>Loading posts..</h1>}
          {data && (
            <Transition.Group>
              {posts &&
                posts.map((post) => (
                  <Grid.Column key={post.id} style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
                    <PostCard post={post} />
                  </Grid.Column>
                ))}
            </Transition.Group>
          )}
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
  if(error) {
    return error.message;
  }

 }
  


export default Home;
```

I render all the posts in `Home.js`

Resolvers => **posts.js :**

```
const { AuthenticationError, UserInputError } = require('apollo-server');

const Post = require('../../models/Post');
const checkAuth = require('../../util/check-auth');

module.exports = {
  Query: {
    async getPosts() {
      try {
        const posts = await Post.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 });
        return posts;
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
      }
    },
    async getPost(_, { postId }) {
      try {
        const post = await Post.findById(postId);
        if (post) {
          return post;
        } else {
          throw new Error('Post not found');
        }
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
      }
    }
  },
  Mutation: {
    async createPost(_, { body }, context) {
      const user = checkAuth(context);

      if (body.trim() === '') {
        throw new Error('Post body must not be empty');
      }

      const newPost = new Post({
        body,
        user: user.id,
        username: user.username,
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
      });

      const post = await newPost.save();

      context.pubsub.publish('NEW_POST', {
        newPost: post,
      }).then(()=>{
        console.log("working")
      });

      return post;
    },
    async deletePost(_, { postId }, context) {
      const user = checkAuth(context);

      try {
        const post = await Post.findById(postId);
        if (user.username === post.username) {
          await post.delete();
          return 'Post deleted successfully';
        } else {
          throw new AuthenticationError('Action not allowed');
        }
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
      }
    },
    async likePost(_, { postId }, context) {
      const { username } = checkAuth(context);

      const post = await Post.findById(postId);
      if (post) {
        if (post.likes.find((like) => like.username === username)) {
          // Post already likes, unlike it
          post.likes = post.likes.filter((like) => like.username !== username);
        } else {
          // Not liked, like post
          post.likes.push({
            username,
            createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
          });
        }

        await post.save();
        return post;
      } else throw new UserInputError('Post not found');
    }
  },
  Subscription: {
    newPost: {
      subscribe: (_, __, { pubsub }) => pubsub.asyncIterator('NEW_POST')
    }
  }
};
```

Resolvers => **index.js :**

```
const postsResolvers = require('./posts');
const usersResolvers = require('./users');
const commentsResolvers = require('./comments');

module.exports = {
  Post: {
    likeCount: (parent) => parent.likes.length,
    commentCount: (parent) => parent.comments.length
  },
  Query: {
    ...postsResolvers.Query
  },
  Mutation: {
    ...usersResolvers.Mutation,
    ...postsResolvers.Mutation,
    ...commentsResolvers.Mutation
  },
  Subscription: {
    ...postsResolvers.Subscription
  }
};
```

**tyDefs.js :**

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server');

module.exports = gql`
  type Post {
    id: ID!
    body: String!
    createdAt: String!
    username: String!
    comments: [Comment]!
    likes: [Like]!
    likeCount: Int!
    commentCount: Int!
  }
  type Comment {
    id: ID!
    createdAt: String!
    username: String!
    body: String!
  }
  type Like {
    id: ID!
    createdAt: String!
    username: String!
  }
  type User {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
    token: String!
    username: String!
    createdAt: String!
  }
  input RegisterInput {
    username: String!
    password: String!
    confirmPassword: String!
    email: String!
  }
  type Query {
    getPosts: [Post]
    getPost(postId: ID!): Post
  }
  type Mutation {
    register(registerInput: RegisterInput): User!
    login(username: String!, password: String!): User!
    createPost(body: String!): Post!
    deletePost(postId: ID!): String!
    createComment(postId: String!, body: String!): Post!
    deleteComment(postId: ID!, commentId: ID!): Post!
    likePost(postId: ID!): Post!
  }
  type Subscription {
    newPost(    
    id: ID!,
    body: String!,
    createdAt: String!,
    username: String!,
    likeCount: Int!,
    commentCount: Int!): Post!
  }
`;
```

This is the **index.js** file of my server (backend) :

```
const { ApolloServer, PubSub } = require('apollo-server');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const typeDefs = require('./graphql/typeDefs');
const resolvers = require('./graphql/resolvers');
const { MONGODB } = require('./config.js');

const pubsub = new PubSub();

const PORT = process.env.port || 5000;

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: ({ req }) => ({ req, pubsub })
});

mongoose
  .connect(MONGODB,  { useUnifiedTopology: true ,  useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('MongoDB Connected');
    return server.listen({ port: PORT });
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(`Server running at ${res.url}`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
  })
```

I am intialising the pubsub in the index.js file only,
This is the error I am getting :

> TypeError: data.getPosts is not iterable   0.chunk.js:124321

Screen shot of the error :
[image: pic of the error]

This error is one problem the other is that whenever I click submit the same error occurs, but the post appears when I run the subscription in `Graphql` Playground not in the client page but when I refresh the page the post appears there.

Comment: Why everybody doesn't want to answer my question, I am stuck with this error for hours now. Should I make any changes to my question like add some code instead of github repo??

Comment: you need to put the code what you've tried not the images/videos/githubs

Comment: Thanks I will put the code, I did not do so because there was so much code

Comment: @Naren I have the **added the code** of some files, if you want any more files to be added i will add it.

Comment: Based on the error message, I would say, that your ```data.getPosts()``` does not return an array as you would expect. Can you log the output of that and see what is actually being returned?

Comment: Yeah that's true, i had given a alias to `getPosts` as posts, so i renamed it  to posts. The error no longer appears but still my app doesn't work like when i create a post it does get created but appears only after i refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using Apollo v3, and you're having some issues with caching while adding posts:

```
 const [createPost, { error }] = useMutation(CREATE_POST_MUTATION, {
        variables: values,
        update(proxy, result) {
          const data = proxy.readQuery({
            query: FETCH_POSTS_QUERY,
          });
          proxy.writeQuery({
            query: FETCH_POSTS_QUERY,
            data: {
              getPosts: [result.data.createPost, ...data.getPosts],
            },
          });
          values.body = "";
        },
        onError(err) {
     <== also add this so the page doesn't break
          return err;
        },
      });
```